# Extract the array out of the string

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I extract the array out of the string?

Current:

```js
"['Biller.Customer.Data@Taxonomy', 'Product.Platform and Enterprise Services Data.Data@Taxonomy']"
```

Expected:

```js
['Biller.Customer.Data@Taxonomy', 'Product.Platform and Enterprise Services Data.Data@Taxonomy']
```

I tried using regex and it did nothing:

```js
string.replace(/"/g, '')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the original string?

Answer (score 4):

**It will be better to produce a valid [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON) string instead of that format**. However, if you're stuck with that because of a factor out of your control, then you can use or write a parser that can handle it (e.g. [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5)):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKQMoHkByBWOAzKERwBEAVgM4QB2GhA3AFB0DGlp8wFYArvALxEDaAcgBCwADZiAplAB0AYU6t80mQBEAhjHUABACrqAHpXwBPQQBo4ggAp4AJp0YwZ1sZuzQC6inbgBRChhpMChgUkk4JGkAN2BGSVI4DS01TR19IwpTQQBdWgZmClY4dSgodRM4PmR0DBkwUvCACnYuGABKeiYWCCkZMQgAcybS8pNOuAB6Sbh+QlEJFQUlEBVk9MNjEBNCS0JbCAcnFzcYDygvH39A4NDwyJi4hKS01K09Taztwhy6IA)

```html
<script type="module">

import JSON5 from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/json5@2.2.3/dist/index.min.mjs";

const input = "['Biller.Customer.Data@Taxonomy', 'Product.Platform and Enterprise Services Data.Data@Taxonomy']";

const array = JSON5.parse(input);

console.log(array); // ["Biller.Customer.Data@Taxonomy", "Product.Platform and Enterprise Services Data.Data@Taxonomy"]

</script>
```

Or, if you understand and accept the dangers of string evaluation, you can also use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmADgV1gXhgIgNoHIBCcANkQKYBOAdAMLLQgC2FlAIgIZRsACAKmwB7hGAT1wAaGLgAK5EABNkwKJSlEOAMxDkGMNmDkwAomCgVE5OBFIwAyhQBucYKQgx2nVh259BYEbgBdTABuAChQ0EhYNnJyNmEYDFJ7NiIACgQUKABKMIjwCBAySiIQAHM0mLjhXJgAejqYbExCEmZaeiYqd28BIQZhTAlMGXlFZVUNLR09A2NTcnNLaztyR2dXHs9OXj6-AcwA0KA)

```js
const input = "['Biller.Customer.Data@Taxonomy', 'Product.Platform and Enterprise Services Data.Data@Taxonomy']";

const array = eval(input);

console.log(array); // ["Biller.Customer.Data@Taxonomy", "Product.Platform and Enterprise Services Data.Data@Taxonomy"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JSON.parse`, but note that single quotes are not valid string delimiters in JSON, use `replaceAll` to change them to double quotes if you are not the one generating the string. If you are in control of the original string, just use double quotes as delimiters instead.

`JSON.parse(yourString.replaceAll("'", '"'))` could solve your problem, but it is very risky, since if one of your strings had an apostrophe, that would become invalid json, thus `JSON.parse` would throw an error.

Note: Pay VERY close attention to the single and double quotes in the `replaceAll`

Comment: That did not work. That is what I first tried. I get this error: Error: Unexpected token ''', "['Biller.Cu"... is not valid JSON

Comment: Okay, in that case I need more specifics.

You have the string `"['Biller.Customer.Data@Taxonomy', 'Product.Platform and Enterprise Services Data.Data@Taxonomy']"`. Are the double quotes actually part of the string or did you just put them there to show it's a string?

Comment: Also, single quotes are not valid in JSON, they must be double quotes inside the brackets `[]`

Comment: I have updated my answer to account for the single quotes, but I need you to answer the question in my first comment to know if it needs to be changed to account for the double quotes as well

Comment: I am waiting for backend team to change the response to use double quotes, so I don't have to manipulate it myself. Thanks for you solution.

Comment: That is definitely the best solution as any kind of manual manipulation would be risky, for example if one of your strings actually had an apostrophe in it, my `replaceAll` suggestion would throw an error, as that would generate invalid JSON. I've updated my answer to account for this possibility

Answer (score 0):

```
myarray=(this.stringArray.match(/\'([^,])*\'/g) ||[])
          .map(x=>x.slice(0,-1).slice(1))
```